# How to export the list of soft-clipped regions from a region of interest in IGV

Tags: sam, igv

I want to export the list of soft-clipped regions into a csv file from a region of interest in IGV. Additional information regarding the soft-clipped sequence, coordinate and nucleotide length will be helpful.
[image]

PFB the output file format

| Gene | Variant |
| --- | --- |
| FLT3 | chr13:28034082C>CAAACTCTAAATTTTCTCTTGGAAACTCCCATTTGAGATCATATAG |
| FLT3 | chr13:28034113T>TTTGAGATCATATTCATATTCTCTGAAATCAACGTAGAAGTACTCATTATCTGAGGAGCCGGTCACCTGTACCACC |

Comment: Does this have to be done from IGV?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and add an example of the output format you want to see. What _exact_ fields should be in the csv?